# Create stored procedure activity from python for ADF V2

Tags: python, azure-data-factory

Getting the following error for code that creates stored procedure activity for ADF V2.

> Unable to build a model: Unable to deserialize response data. Data: {DateToImportFor :{value:2017-01-04,type:str}}, {StoredProcedureParameter}, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items', DeserializationError: Unable to deserialize response data. Data: {DateToImportFor :{value:2017-01-04,type:str}}, {StoredProcedureParameter}, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

My code:

```
spActivity_Name="AzureSQLDWStoredProcedureActivity"
storedproc_name ="DailyImport"
linkedService = LinkedServiceReference(lsdw)
p="{%s :{value:%s,type:str}}" % ('DateToImportFor','2017-01-04')


lsp_activity = SqlServerStoredProcedureActivity(name=spActivity_Name,
                                       stored_procedure_name=storedproc_name,
                                       stored_procedure_parameters=p,
                                       linked_service_name=linkedService)
```

Since I am very new to python, I am not sure how to construct the parameters object.

```
#stored_procedure_parameter is expecting in the following format
  :param stored_procedure_parameters: Value and type setting for stored
     procedure parameters. Example: "{Parameter1: {value: "1", type: "int"}}".
    :type stored_procedure_parameters: dict[str,
     ~azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.StoredProcedureParameter]
    """


p_name =  'StoredProcPipeLine'
params_for_pipeline = {}
p_obj = PipelineResource(activities=[lsp_activity], parameters=params_for_pipeline)
p = adf_client.pipelines.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, p_name, p_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Example on documentation is a little bit inaccurate, since it states the example for `stored_procedure_parameters` as a string.

Try setting p as a dictionary:

```
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import StoredProcedureParameter
p = {'DateToImportFor': StoredProcedureParameter('2017-01-04', type='String')}
```