# Creating azure datafactory stored procedure activity parameters

Tags: python, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory, azure-python-sdk

I am trying to create a stored procedure activity in azure data factory python sdk. Although the task can receive the value and the type of stored procedure parameters, I am not being able to pass the name of the parameter using StoredProcedureParameter class. Any suggestions?

ps: Already read the documentation and tried to pass as a dict. Did not worked.

-> The result in Azure Data Factory portal
[image: The result on Azure Data Factory portal]

-> Creating the parameters via python sdk
[image: Creating the parameters via python sdk]

Comment: [Create stored procedure activity from python for ADF V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47984623/create-stored-procedure-activity-from-python-for-adf-v2), [StoredProcedureParameter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.storedprocedureparameter?view=azure-python) and [StoredProcedureParameterType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.storedprocedureparametertype?view=azure-python)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT I've tried this documentation, but the name parameter is not a part of the class. And I've already tried the dict form to pass as well. The azure didnt recognize the parameter and created as 0, Null, Null, for example.

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Using the example of the first link, I got the following return: __TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given__

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.